# Передача из С++ команды командной строке

Tags: cmd, visual-studio, распараллеливание, c++, mpi

Необходимо запустить с помощью командной строки mpi прогу большое число раз в цикле для подсчета среднего времени ее выполнения. Для этого создам отдельную С++ прогу (не mpi), в которой в цикле будет вызываться командная строка с командами

```
cd C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin
```

а затем необходимо этой командной строке предать команду

```
mpiexec -n количество процессов путь к mpi-проге
```

(внутри которой будет происходить измерение ее времени средствами mpi). Какие есть команды в С++ для этого?

Comment: 1. Такие вещи проще делать через скрипты оболочки.
2. Так какую же строку должна получить консоль? Я что-то не понял.

Comment: Две строки:

- сначала `cd C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin`
- а затем `mpiexec -n количество процессов путь к mpi-проге`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала Вы хотите сменить текущую директорию. Лучше это сделать методами С++. В юниксах для этого есть системный вызов chdir(). В виндовсе наверняка тоже есть что-то подобное. Поищите.

Потом Вы хотите выполнить mpiexec и передать ей несколько параметров. Это можно сделать несколькими методами.

1. использовать  system(). Если хотите поменять параметр -n, то можно сформировать строку либо с помощью класса string, либо в стиле С с помощью sprintf().
2. С помощью _popen(). Он возвращает указатель на FILE, из которого можете прочитать то, что исполняемая программа посылает в stdout.
3. С помощью API функций типа exec.

P.S. Сменить текущую директорию можно с помощью функции [_chdir()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

Не подойдёт? А вообще такие вещи водятся не в C/C++, а в используемой системе. Если нужны заморочки с путями, перенаправлением ввода/вывода -- тогда надо смотреть API системы (в данном случае, как я понимаю, это винды). Насчет двух комманд -- так вроде cmd.exe разрешает их писать вместе, через ";"

Comment: После выполения mpi-проги в консоли появится строка `C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin`. Каким образом можно ее прочитать? Если есть ссылки на данные команды, то поместите их в ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте popen()

Comment: В винде худо-бедно работают пайпы. `programm1 | programm2 | programm2 > logfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

использовать CreateProcess

Answer (score 0):

Использовать средства операционной системы. Например команду шела - FOR. При этом вполне можно запускать как последовательно, так и параллельно (используя START ключи).